# Is Abelian Group Subset consisting of elements of finite order a Subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know this question has asked and answered before, so my apologies for posting a duplicate query.  Instead of the solution, I'm seeking a "nudge" in the right direction to complete the proof on my own.  So please, hints or criticism only.  Thanks!

"Show that in an Abelian group $G$, the set consisting of all elements of $G$ of finite order is a subgroup of $G$."

Let $H\subset G$ consisting of all elements of a finite order.  Then $H$ contains the inverse element $e \in G$, since $e^1 = e$.

Next, let $a \in G$ such that $a^n = e$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  So $a \in H$, and $a^{-1} \in H$ since $(a^{-1})^n = (a^{n})^{-1} = e^{-1} = e$. Hence the order of $a^{-1}$ is finite, and $H$ is closed under inverses.

Last, let $b^{m} = e \in G$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Then $b \in H$ $ab \in G$.  To show $ab \in H$, notice that $e = ee = a^{n}b^{m}$ and 
$$a^{n}b^{m} = (ab)a^{n-1}b^{m-1}$$
since $G$ is Abelian. So $ab \in H$ and $H$ is closed under the operation of $G$. So $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

This last part I'm nearly certain is wrong.  I've tried to use the fact that $G$ is Abelian to manipulate the equation $$ab = ba$$ using left and right multiplication in as many ways as I can think of to yield a proof that the order of $ab$ is finite. As usual, I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, and would appreciate any advice pointing towards, rather than disclosing,  the solution.

Comment: Everything seems fine until the last part. Why is $(ab)\in H$. You need to show it has finite order (i.e. $(ab)^k=e$ for some $k$. What could you take for $k$?

Comment: I'm thinking m*n.

Comment: Give it a try.  Does it work?

Comment: It does work.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Suppose that $a,b\in H$; you need to show that $ab\in H$. There are positive integers $m,n$ such that $a^m=b^n=e$; use the fact that $G$ is Abelian to show that $(ab)^{mn}=e$ and hence that $ab\in H$. Basically this requires showing by induction that $(ab)^k=a^kb^k$ for $k\ge 0$.

Comment: Thanks you guys.  Reframing the question as $(ab)^{k} = e$ for what $k$is exactly the nudge I needed.

Comment: @ScentlessApprentice: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another take.

Consider $G_n = \{ x \in G : x^n = e \}$. It is easy to prove that $G_n$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Moreover, $G_m \subseteq G_n$ when $m \mid n$. In particular, $G_m$ and $G_n$ are contained in $G_{mn}$.

The subgroup you want is the *torsion subgroup* of $G$, denoted by $\operatorname{tor}(G)$.

It follows from the definiton that $\operatorname{tor}(G)=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} G_n$.

It now follows that $\operatorname{tor}(G)$ is a subgroup because every group operation you need to perform happens in one of the $G_n$. In particular, if $a\in G_m$ and $b\in G_n$, then $ab \in G_{mn}$.